# Для чего стоит указывать @pyqtSlot() перед методами? (PyQt5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, декоратор

Изучаю *PyQt5* по книге Прохоренка. В ней написано, что **`@pyqtSlot()`** ускоряет выполнение метода.

Решил проверить, правда ли это. Создал функцию, в нее запихнул сначала мелкий цикл - до 10.000, затем побольше - до 200.000, и в конечном итоге - до 2 млн.

Каждый раз проводил замеры с использованием **`@pyqtSlot()`** и без него. Все 3 замера выиграл вариант, в котором не используется `pyqtSlot()`. Для сравнения - при 2 млн метод с `pyqtSlot()` показал результат в 66 секунд, когда без его использования выдало 60.5 секунд.

Так почему же стоит использовать этот декоратор, если без него код выполняется быстрее? Или его стоит использовать только в том случае, если функция будет работать куда дольше 60 секунд?

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys
import time

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.start = time.time()
        self.fun()
    @pyqtSlot()
    def fun(self):
        for i in range(2000000):
            print(i)
        end = time.time()
        print(end - self.start)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, ваше тестовое приложение.

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос

Comment: [doc](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator) там есть такая фраза `Connecting a signal to a decorated Python method also has the advantage of reducing the amount of memory used and is slightly faster.` Слегка быстрее ) Вообще, по моим наблюдениям, этот декоратор нужен только для того, чтобы видеть какой метод является и где находится слот, и какие типы аргументов у него есть. И с ним и без него все работает )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Там где вы читаете, речь видимо идет о сигналах и слотах.

Декоратор **`pyqtSlot()`** является частью синтаксиса сигналов и слотов.

Ваш пример никакого отношения к сигналам и слотам не имеет.

Вот вам пример, попробуйте

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.button = QPushButton('Button', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        
        self.start = time.time()
        
#        self.fun()
        QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.fun)           # +++
        
    def fun(self):
        for i in range(2_000_000):
            self.button.click()                     # - print(i)
        end = time.time()
        print(end - self.start)

    @pyqtSlot()                                     # +++ <----
    def on_clicked(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Надо же! Я думал, что разница составит доли секунды, но разница в 4 раза по скорости выполнения меня шокировала

Comment: @Bitchdragon значит правду пишет Прохоренка  :)